# CSS3 transform get scale3d values from Matrix

Tags: css, matrix, transform

I have the following CSS Transform matrix:

```
-webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.38241679238457066, 1.6564291101348998, 0, 0, -1.6564291101348998, 0.38241679238457066, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

I know that it represents the following:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(77deg) scale3d(1.7, 1.7, 1.7);
```

You can see my element at http://jsfiddle.net/xNVZc/

How can I get scale3d values from that matrix?

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transforms and transitions can get a bit confusing while working with them via JavaScript.

It seems that jQuery returns a matrix on every transform that is being set with CSS (or JavaScript).

Also notice that one can only retrieve a style property in a browser that supports that particular feature (in your case -webkit-transform and 3D transformations).